# Convert color object to readable array

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I want to make a negative of an image in Java, but I'm not sure how to convert a `Color` object into an array which can be manipulated. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Color col;
col = picture.getPixel(x,y).getColor();
//x and y are from a for loop
picture.getPixel(x,y).setColor(~~~);
```

`setColor` takes three integers, one for each color channel RBG. I want to convert `Color col` to an array which I can read. Something like the below:

```
picture.getPixel(x,y).setColor(255-col[0],255-col[1],255-col[2]);
```

`255-col[n]` of course creates a negative of the pixel, but `Color col` is not an array when I'd like to access it as one. How can I cast a `Color` object as an array?

I could do something like the below and not use a `Color` object at all,

```
r = picture.getPixel(x,y).getRed(); //r is now an integer 0-255
//repeat the above for green and blue
picture.getPixel(x,y).setColor(r,g,b);
```

But I'd much rather do it in one line.

Comment: Color has 3 methods: getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Perhaps using these values and manipulating them to your needs will suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
int [] arrayRGB = new int[3];
arrayRGB[0] = col.getRed();
arrayRGB[1] = col.getGreen();
arrayRGB[2] = col.getBlue();
```

Or directly :

```
picture.getPixel(x,y).setColor(255-col.getRed(),255-col.getGreen(),255-col.getBlue());
```

Take a look at the [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast `Color` as an array, but you can get it's components as an array:

```
int[] rgb = new int[] { col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), col.getBlue() };
```

You might want to just use these directly.